# What happens if we delete the files from /var/www/html but don't delete the database from mysql

Tags: wordpress

I've inherited a server with Wordpress installed. To uninstall Wordpress steps shared in other queries are that we need to first delete the Wordpress files from `/var/www/html` and then delete the wordpress database from MySQL.

My question is, what happens if we delete the Wordpress files from `/var/www/html` but don't delete the Wordpress database from MySQL. Will Wordpress still be present? What can be its impacts?

Comment: Why would you leave the wordpress database entries when you remove the application?

Comment: The easy way would have been to have installed Wordpress using your package manager. Then you could use that same package manager to remove it.

Comment: @BulletBob, Actually I am not sure how was it installed in the first place, I am trying to uninstall it to verify few things. My idea is to just keep the DB intact for backup purposes backup in case it is needed later.

Comment: @roaima, I understand its of no use to keep database withoit supporting application, and as I said it wasn't installed by me so I didn't want to delete it considering may be it can be needed later.

Comment: @akhilkumarjha Welcome, the database is tied to the specific instance of application it was supporting, I can't imagine how it can be used it without the original application... unless you are browsing data directly from the database.

Comment: Split the difference - make a full sql dump of the database it connected to for backup purposes, then remove the database and the user.

Answer (score 1):

There are typically three parts to a web application such as Wordpress

1. The application code
2. The application instance metadata, stored in a database
3. The application instance content (data), usually stored in the filesystem

(There are other essential components, such as supporting frameworks, the web server itself, etc., but those are not part of the application so I'm not counting them here.)

If you delete the application but leave the metadata and content, you could in principle reinstall another copy of the application at a later date and reuse the old metadata and content.

The metadata and content are tied together. The metadata describes the content: what it is and where to find it. If you delete either the metadata or the content, the other part becomes useless.

Once you delete both metadata and content, you can reuse the application code to generate a fresh instance of the application.

When you have deleted the application code, the database containing the metadata, and the application content, you should also look to removing the corresponding configuration from your webserver. If this webserver was dedicated to the Wordpress instance it can also be safely removed.